# Can you add weightings to values for linear regression?

Tags: math, statistics, linear-regression

I'm trying to develop a predictive model that uses previously collected data to estimate a future value. The data in question is taken from measurements made over several days, however the more recently collected data is more likely to be an accurate estimate of the next value than older data. I was wondering if there was a way to add 'weightings' to values, such that the more recently collected data has a greater impact on the line of best fit in comparison to older data?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: https://towardsdatascience.com/weighted-linear-regression-2ef23b12a6d7

Comment: From what I can tell, this method adds weightings to values based on their standard deviation, but I'm looking to add weightings to value based on the order in which they appear in the sequences - or am I missing something?

Comment: I’d look into Markov chains.  They weight by recency.